# Digest authentification in Geoserver not working

Tags: geoserver, curl

I am trying to use Digest authentification in Geoserver. But when I send a Curl request I get the 401 error.

I followed this tutorial :
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/digest/index.html

Here is the request:

```
curl --digest -v -u admin:password -G "localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET /geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1&SERVICE=WMS HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 401
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="GeoServer Realm"
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1102
< Date: Sun, 13 May 2018 21:22:34 GMT
 <
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.5.5 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - Full authentication is required to access this resource</h1><div class="line"></div><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Full authentication is required to access this resource</u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP auth* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact entication.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.5</h3></body></html>
```

I am using Geoserver v2.13

Comment: please look in the log file and add any error messages to your question

Comment: Actually The only thing related to this in the log file is this             **2018-05-14 20:08:10,287 INFO [geoserver.wms] -
Request: getServiceInfo**

Comment: you may need to turn the logging level up to developer to see anything interesting